# Removing recurring vowels in a string

Tags: java, string

this is the program can anyone help me
at first i have given the string first part is working fine it finds the vowels in string and it prints

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String a = "History can also refer to the academic discipline ";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {  

        if (a.charAt(i) == 'a' || a.charAt(i) == 'e' || a.charAt(i) == 'i' || a.charAt(i) == 'u'
                || a.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            System.out.println("The sentence have vowels:" + a.charAt(i));
            count++;//counting the number of vowels
        }
        if (a.charAt(i+1) == 'a' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'e' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'i' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'u'
                || a.charAt(i+1) == 'u') {i++;}//finding reoccurring vowels 
    }
    System.out.println("number of vowels:" + count);
}
```

}

in second part im trying to skip the reoccurring vowels but its not working

Comment: ***a.charAt(i+1)*** this will explode n the last iteration of the for loop

Comment: You are checking for 'u' 2 times and for 'o' zero times

Comment: my bad i typed "u" instead of "o" but still im having trouble removing reoccurring vowels so what should i do to correct it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of changes:

- Run the loop till `a.length() - 1` as you are already checking for `i+1`st character inside the loop
- Reset the count if the second `if` condition is not satisfied.

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String a = "History can also refer to the academic discipline ";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length() - 1; i++) {  

        if (a.charAt(i) == 'a' || a.charAt(i) == 'e' || a.charAt(i) == 'i' || a.charAt(i) == 'u'
                || a.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            System.out.println("The sentence have vowels:" + a.charAt(i));
            count++;//counting the number of vowels
        }
        //finding reoccurring vowels
        if (a.charAt(i+1) == 'a' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'e' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'i' || a.charAt(i+1) == 'u'
                || a.charAt(i+1) == 'u') {
            i++;
         } else{
            count = 0;
         } 
    }
    System.out.println("number of vowels:" + count);
}
```

Comment: i tried that the output was this but i only wanted to ignore repeating vowel
(The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:e
number of vowels:0)

Comment: @MuthuAkilan do you not want to count consecutive vowels only? You can remove sysout to get rid of those statements in the console.

Comment: i dont want to count and print consecutive vowel....i dont understand how u want me to do ? i want the program itself to omit consecutive array

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "History can also refer to the academic discipline ";
    int count = 0;

    boolean lastWasVowel = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

        if (a.charAt(i) == 'a' || a.charAt(i) == 'e' || a.charAt(i) == 'i' || a.charAt(i) == 'o'
                || a.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            if(!lastWasVowel) {
                count++;
            }
            lastWasVowel = true;
         } else {
            lastWasVowel = false;
        }
     }
    System.out.println("number of vowels:" + count);
}
```

Comment: The sentence have vowels:i
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:o
The sentence have vowels:e
The sentence have vowels:e
The sentence have vowels:o
The sentence have vowels:e
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:a
The sentence have vowels:e
The sentence have vowels:i
The sentence have vowels:i
The sentence have vowels:i
The sentence have vowels:i
The sentence have vowels:e
number of vowels:16

Comment: it didnt ignore repeated vowel word